# Base64 SVG string does not render patterns

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am having a bit weird issue here. I am developing an application where I have to load svg then convert it to base64 to set source of img tag. I have to do that so I can modify svg and then convert it again and show in img tag. The issue I am having here is sometimes I have to apply pattern fill to svg string which doesnt render when converted to base64. If I put the svg string in a div tag using innerhtml I can see pattern applied to it. I am bit of lost here. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong. Here is the code I use.

Piece of code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    
    
    <body style="margin:0">
    
    </body>
    
    <script language="javascript">
        let svg =
            `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="width:2048px;height:2048px"
        width="2048px" height="2048px" x="0px" y="0px" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2048 2048">
            <g id="rect" fill="#FF0000">
                <rect width="2048" height="2048" x="0" y="0"/>
            </g>
            <defs>
                <pattern id="RFLS2MGRY1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="409" height="455" >    
                <image id="Medium Grey"  xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" x="0" y="0" width="409" height="455" />
                </pattern>    
            </defs>
        </svg>`
    
        let svgImage = new Image();
        document.body.appendChild(svgImage);
        const updateInternal = () => {
            svgImage.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(
                XMLToString(svgData)))));
        }
        const applyPattern = (clip) => {
            let $clip = svgData.documentElement.querySelectorAll(`[id=rect]`)
            console.log($clip[0])
            let css = `url(#RFLS2MGRY1)`;
            $clip[0].style.fill = css;
            updateInternal();
        }
        const applyColor = (clip) => {
            let $clip = svgData.documentElement.querySelectorAll(`[id=rect]`)
            console.log($clip[0])
            let css = `#FFFF00`;
            $clip[0].style.fill = css;
            updateInternal();
        }
        const XMLToString = (oXML) => {
            //code for IE
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                var oString = oXML.xml;
                return oString;
            }
            // code for Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            else {
                return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oXML);
            }
        }
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        svgData = parser.parseFromString(svg, "image/svg+xml");
        updateInternal();
        setTimeout(applyColor, 1000);
        setTimeout(applyPattern, 3000);
    </script>
    </html>
```

as you can see it apply changes color fine but not the pattern, no matter if that pattern image is cached, loaded before applying it or serve from my server.

Comment: What do you actually see and what are you expecting to see here?

Comment: Pretty sure that this is not an issue of the Base64 encoding per se, but rather due to the fact that you are embedding the SVG into the document using an `img` element. When you do that, the SVG gets severely limited in how it can interact with the “outside world” - parent page CSS doesn’t apply, JS can not fully interact with it, etc. - you need to embed it directly as an `svg` element into your document, if you want this stuff to work.

Comment: More precisely, the pattern content references an external url. A data URL must be self-contained.

Comment: To fix this I have to fetch pattern image over server then convert it to DataURL and then set this as xlink:href of pattern tag. Thanks @ccprog